# show that $\inf \{x_n+y_n:n>N\}\ge \inf \{x_n:n>N\}+\inf \{y_n:n>N\}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

show that $\inf \{x_n+y_n:n>N\}\ge \inf \{x_n:n>N\}+\inf \{y_n:n>N\}$.

I am stuck on proving this. I understand it intuitively. 
My approach is to first do the right part. By defining the infs of yn and xn. But don't see how to move forward.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose first that $\inf\{y_n:n>N\}=L$, a real number.  Then, for each $n$, we have $x_n+y_n\ge x_n+L$, and hence $$\inf\{x_n+y_n:n>N\}\ge \inf\{x_n+L:n>N\}=\inf\{x_n:n>N\}+L=\inf\{x_n:n>N\}+\inf\{y_n:n>N\}$$

On the other hand, if $\inf\{y_n:n>N\}=-\infty$, then the RHS of your inequality might not be well-defined, since it involves adding a real number to $-\infty$.  If you extend $\mathbb{R}$ to include $-\infty$, then the RHS will always be $-\infty$, so the inequality is always true.